# Doing a reverse search with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have problem with pymongo. If i do a search, pymongo begins with last added docomuent to searh  and give me last document but i need to find 8 first added document. How to do this?

This my acctual code

```
Database.find({"idUser":userId}).limit(8)
```

I try to find some like this.

```
Database.reverse.find({"idUser":userId}).limit(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, DESCENDING
db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.find().sort('idUser', DESCENDING).limit(8)
```

Replace `idUser` with the field you wish to sort by.

Reference:

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=sort#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort